# How are you meant to use the middle mouse button?

Tags: shortcut

I am switching to Blender from Maya, I was really happy when I heard about the 'industry standard' keymap, but there are many tools missing in there so I thought I would try out the blender keymap, but it feels quite uncomfortable panning around with the middle mouse button, how are you meant to do it? Do you have three fingers on the mouse and use the middle one for the middle mouse button? or just two fingers and the index finger switches between the left and middle buttons?

Comment: I have voted to close this question as primarily-opinion based, because it is not about the usage of Blender, but about operating 3 buttons on a computer mouse. You can reconfigure Blenders Keymap to set up viewport tracking, panning and thumbling like Maya. Please take advise about which finger to use lighty as this should vary for every individual. A good hand for one person position may not be ergonomic or healthy for another.

Answer (score 1):

I use my index finger and switch between the left and middle buttons. You won't need to use both buttons at the same time. If you want you can use three fingers on the mouse, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Blender 2.8 is configured so that pressing the middle mouse button while dragging the axis around activates the `Axis Snap` which is used for looking around the view-port.

A way to browse around a scene if you will; seems to be the default most requested operation on new installs.